# Does $\Phi(A^\dagger) = \Phi^\dagger(A)$?

Tags: quantum-operation

Define linear map $\Phi \in T(X)$, linear operator $A \in L(X)$.
Is it true that
\begin{equation}
\Phi(A^\dagger) = \Phi^\dagger(A)?
\tag{1}
\end{equation}
What are the conditions that will let equation $(1)$ hold?

Comment: what is $\Phi^\dagger$ here? Do you mean the adjoint map, or do you mean $\Phi(A)^\dagger$, that is, the adjoint/Hermitian conjugate of the operator $\Phi(A)$? Also, what's the context of the question, is it from a textbook?

Comment: I would consider the Kraus decomposition.

Comment: $\Phi^\dagger$ is the adjoint map here. This question is the guesswork not from a textbook.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The adjoint map $\Phi^\dagger$ is linear by definition. However, $^\dagger$ is anti-linear. Therefore, the right hand side of $(1)$ is linear, but the left hand side is anti-linear. This is only possible if $\Phi$ is the zero map.

In a little more detail, on one hand
$$
\Phi^\dagger(iA)=\Phi((iA)^\dagger)=\Phi(-iA^\dagger)=-i\Phi(A^\dagger)\tag2
$$
but on the other
$$
\Phi^\dagger(iA)=i\Phi^\dagger(A)=i\Phi(A^\dagger)\tag3
$$
so $\Phi(A^\dagger)=-\Phi(A^\dagger)$ and $\Phi$ is the zero map.